# Hibernate, @JoinTable & JoinColumns make an insert that doesnt include a not null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So I have a function:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "tablename", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =     "idvalue1"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idvalue2"))
```

This creates the statement:

```
Hibernate: insert into tablename (idvalue1, idvalue2) values (?, ?)
```

Now the problem is that in the table "tablename" it requires one more value every time a value is set which can be any number but its still a not null value. So the statement should be :

```
Hibernate: insert into tablename (idvalue1, idvalue2,notnullNum) values (?, ?,?)
```

When I put either the inverse or the normal joincolumns in an array it gives me the expecting 1 error. How can I add another value to the jointable to let the insert work